# Where can I find a plugin that will zoom in and out a div's content with a slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Are there any plugins that allows zooming in and out a div and it's content via a slider?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

please refer this nice zoom slider with JQUERY. it may help you

[ZOOM SLIDER](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/12/27/portfolio-zoom-slider/)